# Is it possible to make multiple input and multiple output DNN model when I have different number of data sample for each task

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I would like to implement a multitask deep neural network (DNN) that solves two classification tasks (Task1, Task2) simultaneously.  The problem is I have different number of data for each task and I am not sure whether I can do multitask learning when I have different number of data.

I wrote the following code to implement multiple inputs and multiple outputs DNN. `x_train_T1`, `x_train_T`2 are training data (X) for Task 1 and Task 2 respectively. `y_train_T1` and `y_train_T2` are label data (y) for Task1 and Task 2. `x_train_T1` and `x_train_T2` are same dimension feature vectors (Both are 1443 dimension). But the number of these data is different. For Task1 I have 1213 data samples and for Task2 I have 1271 data samples.

```py
input_T1_tensor=Input(shape=(x_train_T1.shape[1],),name='T1_input')
input_T2_tensor=Input(shape=(x_train_T2.shape[1],),name='T2_input')
concatenated=layers.concatenate([input_T1_tensor,input_T2_tensor],axis=-1)
x=Dropout(concatenated)
x=layers.Dense(x)
T1_layer=layers.Dense(10,activation='relu')(x)
T2_layer=layers.Dense(10,activation='relu')(x)
T1_out=layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name='T1_out')(T1_layer)
T2_out=layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name='T2_out')(T2_layer)
model=Model(inputs=[input_T1_tensor,input_T2_tensor],outputs=[T1_out,T2_out])
model.compile(loss={'T1_out':'binary_crossentropy','T2_out':'binary_crossentropy'},optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([x_train_T1,x_train_T2],[y_train_T1,y_train_T2],epochs=epoch,batch_size=batch,verbose=0,validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message.

```
All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(1213, 1443), (1271, 1443)]
```

If I have the same number of data sample for each task, this code works well.

I would like to know whether it is possible to do multitask learning when I have a different number of
data for each task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. This is not a Keras limitation, but a theoretical issue with the multi-task learning framework, as it assumes that there is a 1:1 relation between samples for each task. This implies that there is the same number of samples for every task.

Even when doing gradient descent it would not make sense, as you have to input one sample for every task/input at the same time, so if the samples per task does not match, then you cannot do this for some samples.

There is no way around this.